# Two bootstrap columns where one has a diagonal edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a menu with a sloped/diagonal edge in bootstrap like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqn13ajg/4/). Although it kinda works I don't like how the div is still scrollable with the mousewheel (though not in the jsfiddle).

This is caused by the `overflow-y: hidden;` property on the container div. Which I use to hide the excess border on my `.slope` div. I can't set any static height values because my content is dynamic.

This makes me wonder if there's a better way to achieve this result.

**HMTL**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="menu col-xs-4">
      <ul>
        <li>1. item</li>
        <li>2. item</li>
        <li>3. item</li>
        <li>4. item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content col-xs-8">
      some content
      <div class="slope"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.slope {
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 1000px solid lightblue;
  border-right: 500px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Where do you getting scroll

Comment: Which browser did you see scroll

Comment: @Sasikumar chrome v53.
please note: I'm not asking for a way to solve the scroll, I'm asking for another way to achieve the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And something like this?

```
.menu {
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1000px solid lightblue;
  border-right: 500px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  top: 0;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqn13ajg/5/)